# R - Rstudio - make R play a sound if warning/error generated

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running a script that loops over a list of stock pair combinations... occasionally the script stops running due to an error generated by differing data lengths between pair combo and I simply remove the mismatched stock from consideration):

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = stckY ~ stckX + 0, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'stckX')
```

Is there any way I can make R / Rstudio play a sound when the error message occurs so that I can be alerted without having to keep my eyes on the screen while the script is looping along?

I can generate sounds linearly using:

```
beep <- function(n = 3){
    for(i in seq(n)){
        system("rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep -1")
        Sys.sleep(.5)
    }
}
beep()
```

but how can I do this conditional on an error message?

Comment: use the [beepr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/beepr/index.html) package

Answer (score 6):

Building on @frankc answer and @hrbrmstr comment, a way to do this:

```
install.packages("beepr")
library(beepr)
options(error = beep)
```

Answer (score 0):

try options(error = beep)

you would still need to define beep before you do this.  Haven't verified this works but it should per ?options:

```
'error': either a function or an expression governing the handling
          of non-catastrophic errors such as those generated by 'stop'
          as well as by signals and internally detected errors.  If the
          option is a function, a call to that function, with no
          arguments, is generated as the expression.  The default value
          is 'NULL': see 'stop' for the behaviour in that case.  The
          functions 'dump.frames' and 'recover' provide alternatives
          that allow post-mortem debugging.  Note that these need to
          specified as e.g.  'options(error = utils::recover)' in
          startup files such as '.Rprofile'.
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out in the future, but for now I figured out a larger solution by just skipping errors altogether using tryCatch()

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing "beepr" and then using beep(8) for a badass super mario bros sound. Maybe with the previous suggestions and this, you could have a good result :) .

```
install.packages("beepr")

[your code here]

beepr::beep(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Gorka answer, you can specify the sound you use for the beep by calling `options(error = function() beep(9))`

Comment: please expand this into a standalone answer crediting the referenced answer for its contribution, or delete this and suggest an edit to the referenced answer post.