# How to judge whether function completed in R?

Tags: r

I want to automatically `beep()` when function is completed(successful runned) or not completed(error)

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58008557/7936836),`options(error = beep)` can be used when function not completed.
[addTaskCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385384/7936836) will be called each time a top-level task is completed.

Then,how to know function is completed?

Comment: As the function's first code line, `on.exit(beep())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package [`beepr`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=beepr), see also [here](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/beepr.html):

> `beepr` is an R package that contains one function, `beep()`, with one
> purpose: To make it easy to play notification sounds on whatever
> platform you are on. It is intended to be useful, for example, if you
> are running a long analysis in the background and want to know when it
> is ready.

See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24516716/8245406).

The following code will beep 5 times, one time per call to `f`. This is because `beep()` is in `on.exit` that, like the name says, executes its argument(s) on exit of the function.

```
f <- function(x){
  on.exit(beepr::beep())
  Sys.sleep(x)
}
g <- function(s) {
  for(i in 1:5) {
    f(s)
  }
}

g(1)
```

Comment: Is there solution without change R script,like `options(error = beep)`

Comment: I am not sure whether has something like `options(on.exit = beep)`?